# OR Tools cp model performance for flexible job shop scheduling with transitions

Tags: python, job-scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

I am evaluating OR tools cp model performance based on example https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/contrib/scheduling_with_transitions_sat.py

I've modified the code to generate random jobs and to learn about run times to retrieve first and "acceptable" solutions - "acceptable" meaning not too many/big emtpy wholes in the schedule.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Scheduling problem with transition time between tasks and transitions costs.

@author: CSLiu2
"""


import argparse
import collections
import random

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from google.protobuf import text_format

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Command line arguments.
PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
PARSER.add_argument(
    '--problem_instance', default=0, type=int, help='Problem instance.')
PARSER.add_argument(
    '--output_proto',
    default='',
    help='Output file to write the cp_model proto to.')
PARSER.add_argument('--params', default='', help='Sat solver parameters.')


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Intermediate solution printer
class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
  """Print intermediate solutions."""

  def __init__(self, makespan):
    cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
    self.__solution_count = 0
    self.__makespan = makespan

  def OnSolutionCallback(self):
    print('Solution %i, time = %f s, objective = %i, makespan = %i' %
          (self.__solution_count, self.WallTime(), self.ObjectiveValue(),
           self.Value(self.__makespan)))
    self.__solution_count += 1


def main(args):
  """Solves the scheduling with transitions problem."""

  instance = args.problem_instance
  parameters = args.params
  output_proto = args.output_proto

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Data.
  # get random jobs
  jobs = []
  sum_tasks = 0

  num_machines = 8
  for i in range(0, 30): # create jobs
      tasks = []
      for j in range(0, random.randint(3, 5)): # create tasks per job
          alternatives = []
          sum_tasks += 1
          machines = list(range(0, num_machines)) # list of machines to randomly pick one for each task
          for k in range(0, 2): # create two alternatives per task
              machineInd = random.randint(0,len(machines)-1)
              alternatives.append((random.randint(6, 35), machines[machineInd], 'R'+str(random.randint(0, 6))))
              del machines[machineInd]
          tasks.append(alternatives)
      jobs.extend([tasks])

  print('total number of tasks: %i' % sum_tasks)
  print('total number of jobs: %i' % len(jobs))
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Helper data.
  num_jobs = len(jobs)
  all_jobs = range(num_jobs)
  all_machines = range(num_machines)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Model.
  model = cp_model.CpModel()

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Compute a maximum makespan greedily.
  horizon = 0
  for job in jobs:
    for task in job:
      max_task_duration = 0
      for alternative in task:
        max_task_duration = max(max_task_duration, alternative[0])
      horizon += max_task_duration

  print('Horizon = %i' % horizon)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Global storage of variables.
  intervals_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  presences_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  starts_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  ends_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  resources_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)
  ranks_per_machines = collections.defaultdict(list)

  job_starts = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
  job_presences = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id, alt_id).
  job_ranks = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id, alt_id).
  job_ends = []  # indexed by job_id

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Scan the jobs and create the relevant variables and intervals.
  for job_id in all_jobs:
    job = jobs[job_id]
    num_tasks = len(job)
    previous_end = None
    for task_id in range(num_tasks):
      task = job[task_id]

      min_duration = task[0][0]
      max_duration = task[0][0]

      num_alternatives = len(task)
      all_alternatives = range(num_alternatives)

      for alt_id in range(1, num_alternatives):
        alt_duration = task[alt_id][0]
        min_duration = min(min_duration, alt_duration)
        max_duration = max(max_duration, alt_duration)

      # Create main interval for the task.
      suffix_name = '_j%i_t%i' % (job_id, task_id)
      start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + suffix_name)
      duration = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                                 'duration' + suffix_name)
      end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix_name)

      # Store the start for the solution.
      job_starts[(job_id, task_id)] = start

      # Add precedence with previous task in the same job.
      if previous_end is not None:
        model.Add(start >= previous_end)
      previous_end = end

      # Create alternative intervals.
      l_presences = []
      for alt_id in all_alternatives:
        ### add to link interval with eqp constraint.
        ### process time = -1 cannot be processed at this machine.
        if jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0] == -1:
          continue
        alt_suffix = '_j%i_t%i_a%i' % (job_id, task_id, alt_id)
        l_presence = model.NewBoolVar('presence' + alt_suffix)
        l_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + alt_suffix)
        l_duration = task[alt_id][0]
        l_end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + alt_suffix)
        l_interval = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
            l_start, l_duration, l_end, l_presence, 'interval' + alt_suffix)
        l_rank = model.NewIntVar(-1, 1000, 'rank' + alt_suffix)
        l_presences.append(l_presence)
        l_machine = task[alt_id][1]
        l_type = task[alt_id][2]

        # Link the original variables with the local ones.
        model.Add(start == l_start).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
        model.Add(duration == l_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
        model.Add(end == l_end).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)

        # Add the local variables to the right machine.
        intervals_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_interval)
        starts_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_start)
        ends_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_end)
        presences_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_presence)
        resources_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_type)
        ranks_per_machines[l_machine].append(l_rank)

        # Store the variables for the solution.
        job_presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)] = l_presence
        job_ranks[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)] = l_rank

      # Only one machine can process each lot.
      model.Add(sum(l_presences) == 1)

    job_ends.append(previous_end)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Create machines constraints nonoverlap process
  for machine_id in all_machines:
    intervals = intervals_per_machines[machine_id]
    if len(intervals) > 1:
      model.AddNoOverlap(intervals)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Transition times and transition costs using a circuit constraint.
  switch_literals = []
  for machine_id in all_machines:
    machine_starts = starts_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_ends = ends_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_presences = presences_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_resources = resources_per_machines[machine_id]
    machine_ranks = ranks_per_machines[machine_id]
    intervals = intervals_per_machines[machine_id]
    arcs = []
    num_machine_tasks = len(machine_starts)
    all_machine_tasks = range(num_machine_tasks)

    for i in all_machine_tasks:
      # Initial arc from the dummy node (0) to a task.
      start_lit = model.NewBoolVar('')
      arcs.append([0, i + 1, start_lit])
      # If this task is the first, set both rank and start to 0.
      model.Add(machine_ranks[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)
      model.Add(machine_starts[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)
      # Final arc from an arc to the dummy node.
      arcs.append([i + 1, 0, model.NewBoolVar('')])
      # Self arc if the task is not performed.
      arcs.append([i + 1, i + 1, machine_presences[i].Not()])
      model.Add(machine_ranks[i] == -1).OnlyEnforceIf(
          machine_presences[i].Not())

      for j in all_machine_tasks:
        if i == j:
          continue

        lit = model.NewBoolVar('%i follows %i' % (j, i))
        arcs.append([i + 1, j + 1, lit])
        model.AddImplication(lit, machine_presences[i])
        model.AddImplication(lit, machine_presences[j])

        # Maintain rank incrementally.
        model.Add(machine_ranks[j] == machine_ranks[i] + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)

        # Compute the transition time if task j is the successor of task i.
        if machine_resources[i] != machine_resources[j]:
          transition_time = 3
          switch_literals.append(lit)
        else:
          transition_time = 0
        # We add the reified transition to link the literals with the times
        # of the tasks.
        model.Add(machine_starts[j] == machine_ends[i] +
                  transition_time).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
    if arcs:
        model.AddCircuit(arcs)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Objective.
  makespan = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
  model.AddMaxEquality(makespan, job_ends)
  makespan_weight = 1
  transition_weight = 5
  #model.Minimize(makespan * makespan_weight +
  #               sum(switch_literals) * transition_weight)
  model.Minimize(makespan)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Write problem to file.
  if output_proto:
    print('Writing proto to %s' % output_proto)
    with open(output_proto, 'w') as text_file:
      text_file.write(str(model))

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Solve.
  solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
  solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 16
  solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 2
  if parameters:
    text_format.Merge(parameters, solver.parameters)
  solution_printer = SolutionPrinter(makespan)
  status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Print solution.
  if status == cp_model.FEASIBLE or status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    for job_id in all_jobs:
      for task_id in range(len(jobs[job_id])):
        start_value = solver.Value(job_starts[(job_id, task_id)])
        machine = 0
        duration = 0
        select = 0
        rank = -1

        for alt_id in range(len(jobs[job_id][task_id])):
          if jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0] == -1:
            continue

          if solver.BooleanValue(job_presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)]):
            duration = jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0]
            machine = jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][1]
            select = alt_id
            rank = solver.Value(job_ranks[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)])

        print(
            '  Job %i starts at %i (alt %i, duration %i) with rank %i on machine %i'
            % (job_id, start_value, select, duration, rank, machine))

    print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Objective value: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    print('Makespan: %i' % solver.Value(makespan))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(PARSER.parse_args())
```

I am testing on a 16 vCPU machine and I've observed the following performance:

- having a total number of slightly below 100 tasks the optimizer often responds a first solution within a couple of seconds. From time to time, it takes up to 60 to 90 seconds to retrieve a first solution
- having a total number slightly above 100 tasks (pretty likely with the above parameters) the performance drops and the optimizer does not return the first solution for many minutes. I've let it run once and it came back with the first solution after 500 seconds.

Here are my questions now:

1. Is this performance to be expected? Or am I overseeing some kind of mis-config in the code?
2. In general, is there something I could do in terms of performance tuning in this example?
3. in such a job shop scheduling task and having a 16 CPU machine running the optimization, what would you say is the "achievable" performance? More specific, I want the optimizer to return the first solution within ~ 15 seconds and to return an "acceptable" solution within 60-90 seconds. In this flexible job shop scheduling task with transition times (and maybe even incorporating due dates per task), how many jobs, tasks, alternatives, machines do you think can the optimizer handle round about to respond within the desired time frames on this specific machine?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Sequence dependent setup times (flexible) jobshops are very hard problems.
Do not expect any proof of optimality for even medium size problems (100 tasks).

The most impactful thing you can do with CP-SAT is to write a greedy first solution heuristics, and hint the solution to the solver. The scheduling heuristics are not tuned for these kind of problems.

Note: there are (some) tricks to improve performance.

- A good one it to compute the min transition between an interval and all the others, and shift this min duration from the transitions to the duration of the interval.
- A second one is implemented in jobshop_sat.cc. It creates a makespan interval (from the makespan to the horizon). This helps with energetic reasoning.